# How to set the Value detemined by aggregate function to a column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle-apex, window-functions

I use oracle Apex.I created a column avg to set it value

```
UPDATE emp 
SET avg = SUM(price) 
OVER (PARTITION BY id)/COUNT(DISTINCT date) OVER(PARTITION BY id);
```

I have sucessfully generated the value i wanted using aggregate function but i am not able to set it to a Column.Suggest how i can set the result of my query to column.

Comment: UPDATE emp 
SET avg = SUM(price) 
OVER (PARTITION BY id)/COUNT(DISTINCT date) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS Price FROM EMP

Comment: tried it dint work.I think we are not supposed to use aggregate functions to set statement.I am not sure however

Comment: Apart from `SUM(price) / COUNT(DISTINCT date)` looking very suspicious, you shouldn't store that value anyway. You are showing the value can be got from existing data, so don't create redundancy. (And you shouldn't use SQL words for names, such as `avg` and `date`.)

Comment: i replaced avg and date variables here. i want to add the data to the existing table thats actually my question.

Answer (score 0):

By getting all your data into CTE and Updating that on Emp table based on ID

Assumed Script :

IN Oracle :

```
    MERGE INTO EMP U
using (
 SELECT    ID
                , SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id)/COUNT(DISTINCT date) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS Rnum
        FROM    EMP
) S
on (u.id = s.id)
when matched then update set U.Avg = S.rnum
```

In SQL SERVER

```
;WITH number AS (
        SELECT    ID
                , SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id)/COUNT(DISTINCT date) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS Avg
        FROM    EMP

    )
    UPDATE  t 
    SET     t.Avg = r.Avg
    FROM    Emp t
            JOIN number r ON t.ID = r.ID;
```

Comment: Are you sure Oracle supports that?